# Deleting Named Ranges with Excel VBA Corrupting File

Tags: excel, vba, range, office365, corrupt

I'm running into a situation where as soon as I run the following lines of code, my file gets corrupted upon close and re-open.

```
Dim MyName As Name
For Each MyName In Names
    ActiveWorkbook.Names(MyName.Name).Delete
Next
```

I had also tried to replace the code above with the following, and get the same impact:

```
Do While CBool(ActiveWorkbook.Names.Count)
    ActiveWorkbook.Names(1).Delete
Loop
```

The error upon re-opening of the file is as follows:
"We found a problem with some content in 'File X.xlsm'.  Do you want us to try to recover as much as we can?  If you trust the source of this workbook, click Yes'.

After this, the file repairs the file by 'repairing or removing the unreadable content' with message 'Removed Feature: External data range from /xl/worksheets/sheet7.xml part'

Any ideas what's going on here?  I'm glad I was able to isolate the code causing the issue, but I'm at a loss.  I'm using Excel for Office 365 MSO 32-bit.

Comment: It sounds like you have an external data query in your workbook, which will create a hidden name. As, incidentally, will using any functions introduced with 2007 or later, so I'd suggest your code needs adjusting to handle things like that.

Answer (score 0):

You do not define the collection that `Names` belongs to.  Try modifying to define the collection of names.

```
Dim MyName As Name
For Each MyName In ActiveWorkbook.Names
    MyName.Delete
Next
```